# Error 404 on photo after getting via details

Tags: google-places-api

When making a call to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk` with my key, a got a correct response. It gives me photos and photo reference. But when searching for the photo, I got a 404 message. I'm doing a search on `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRZAAAAaCHi7iCO7RowcwbEF5dg_QUG3lNW6fr7F_tVLIQ2cy2agD3lvWH2Bms_pvet71mxz7CZaSm3zud8sjPIxN7RrD-pbDHQ6P24yMQS2vJnDFOMHTWx2GowZoQ2GnoAFHU4EhDbUH2QDrCIVXT7JgXg-Ck9GhSlBLEcxhUM7Ewl6LP9cnh4_YYZSQ` for instance (with key). The photo reference is what I got from the above search.

Anything I'm doing wrong? Or could it be a Google caching problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem but only today. 10 hours ago the same code was working fine

Comment: Same for me. The code stopped working today.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the response is not json try removing it:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRZAAAAaCHi7iCO7RowcwbEF5dg_QUG3lNW6fr7F_tVLIQ2cy2agD3lvWH2Bms_pvet71mxz7CZaSm3zud8sjPIxN7RrD-pbDHQ6P24yMQS2vJnDFOMHTWx2GowZoQ2GnoAFHU4EhDbUH2QDrCIVXT7JgXg-Ck9GhSlBLEcxhUM7Ewl6LP9cnh4_YYZSQ&key=yourkey`

I believe there is an issue with a few of the google sources but it may be related to the placeId you are dealing with. The only difference I have noticed is that 404 are returned when hitting this server `https://lh5.googleusercontent.com`  and photos are returned when hitting this server `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com`.

For example, I had success with this placeId -  `ChIJWTLw5D17NYgR0WSz74Ble5s`

Comment: My mistake, I missed my copy/paste. I didn't used json, I just checked it.